# Changing service config during installation

Tags: c#, service, installation

I'm brainstorming a new project idea that I've to make, and there's one thing on my mind that I've not come across before, nor can seem to find any information that relate exactly to my question (I could be wrong and no doubt it will take someone 30 seconds to link me information).

So, Let's say i have a service which deals with some communication, for example some TCP/IP listeners / clients. Now these will need variables like IP/host names, ports etc. but seeing as a service has no GUI, there no way to enter these details after installation, so I'm assuming that the config can be updated during an installation process?

I've seen this done before, for example, in MySQL server service installation. It acts as a GUI from which you can enter details such as your port number preferences and what not and these are used in the service, so my question is: How can this be done?

edit: no doubt the config will be stored in an XML file, so i guess really i'd be looking at reading / writing to this during the installation.

Comment: You should set the appropriate values in the `app.config` during installation. How to do so depends on the installation framework you use.

Comment: I see. What are some common options?